# Collision detection with character controller in Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I have my player which uses character controller for moving. I placed a sprite in the scene and I'd like for when my player collides with the sprite to disable the sprite, like if the player grabs the sprite (which is Doom's 64 chainsaw).

The sprite's collisions of course work well with everything, but not with the player. How can I get proper collision between them?

Comment: Assuming your collision matrix is set correctly for both gameobjects' layer, you need to implement [OnControllerColliderHit](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnControllerColliderHit.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:
1-Attach "Pickable" script to the sprite.
2-Attach "Player" script to the character controller.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pickable : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float radius = 1f;
    private void Start()
    {
        SphereCollider collider = gameObject.AddComponent<SphereCollider>();
        collider.center = Vector3.zero;
        collider.radius = radius;
        collider.isTrigger = true;
    }
}
```

Here is the other script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Pickable pickable = other.GetComponent<Pickable>();
        if(pickable != null)
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```